# email notification on new posts to all registered users in phpbb

Tags: forum, phpbb, phpbb3

Am developing a forum for internal use in our company using phpbb. All users are created by admin, so there is no worry about sparm users. I want to send email notification to all registered users on each new post in a specified forum (say company announcement).

I know there is a subscribe forum functionality. But I dont think its a good way to tell all users to subscribe that forum.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: This extension looks like it would do the job. It provides the option to automatically subscribe to every new topic.
https://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/extension/autosubscribe/

Answer (score 2):

in \includes\functions_user.php

FIND:

```
'user_notify'         => 0,
```

REPLACE IT WITH:

```
'user_notify'         => 1,
```

That will set the reply notification to default for new users.

IF you have already existent users, then run the following query via phpmyadmin:

```
UPDATE phpbb_users
SET user_notify = 1
WHERE user_type <> 2;
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the phpbb code to automatically subscribe them to the forum in question upon registration. That way you don't have to tell the users to manually do that.

Pete

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, if you don't mind doing it, you can send a PM to all registered users every time you post there, with the same content. I'm a member of a phpbb forum where when making a forum post, there's an option to select all registered users.